# append two data frames with unequal columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append two dataframes in pandas which have two different no of columns.

```
Example:
df1
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  3

df2
A  
4
5

Expected concatenated dataframe 

df
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  Null(or)0
5  Null(or)0
```

I am using 
`df1.append(df2)` when the columns are same. But no idea how to deal with unequal no of columns.

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `concat` to join two columns and pass the additional argument `ignore_index=True` to reset the index other wise you might end with `indexes` as `0 1 2 0 1`. For additional information refer [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5]})
df  = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
df
```

Output:

without `ignore_index = True` :

```
    A   B
0   1   1.0
1   2   2.0
2   3   3.0
0   4   NaN
1   5   NaN
```

with `ignore_index = True` :

```
    A   B
0   1   1.0
1   2   2.0
2   3   3.0
3   4   NaN
4   5   NaN
```

---

Answer (score 3):

How about [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)?

```
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2])
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
0  4  NaN
1  5  NaN
```

Also, `df1.append(df2)` still works:

```
>>> df1.append(df2)
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  3.0
0  4  NaN
1  5  NaN
```

From the [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) of `df.append`:

> Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.